# How do I run "srb tc --lsp" properly?

Tags: sorbet

I'm trying to run srb tc --lsp and run into this issue. `srb tc` works fine.

```
$ srb tc --lsp
Sorbet's language server requires a single input directory.
```

I tried to give it a path but it doesn't work:

```
$ srb tc --lsp .
```

What's the correct way to run `srb tc --lsp`?

Edit: it turns out the `sorbet/config` file I have has more than one folder

```
.
@sorbet/rbi_list
```

It works when removing `@sorbet/rbi_list` but I'd need it to include rbis from gems.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no supported way to have two directories. You can copy everything in `sorbet/rbi_list` into your directory but then it will no longer update when the gems do.

This will be solved once `--lsp` leaves experimental mode.